# Can I expose a Kafka queue topic so that it can only be read from by certain subscribers

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a service that is responsible for writing messages to a Kafka queue topic.

I would like to expose that queue topic to another service so it may consume those messages, but I want to restrict that service to only be able to read from the topic, never to be able to write to it.

The documentation seems very vague on whether this is possible (or I have been Googling in the wrong areas).

Any advice or pointers on how to do this would be great.

Thanks,
Raymond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely very late answer but maybe it will help someone in future.

Kafka supports all sorts of authentication and authorisation methods at this very moment. You can secure your environment by connecting it to kerberos or Active Directory you have your company or in other words enabling authentication. (https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html)

Secodn step can be enabling authorisation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html.

You can even take a look at nice project from Open Policy Agent: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html

In short: with even SimpleAuthorisation method which is out of the box available within Kafka project you can "defend" topics. You can easily say which user can do what to topic.

Idea to thought about ->

Guys from streamthoughts created a nice project [kafka-specs](https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-specs). You can easily manage your topics and acls on git in yamls. You can even "envision" namespaces with simple naming convention and let certain teams to handle only their topics and acls via ***their*** yaml on git. You can be the one approving Pull Requests executing (or Jenkins) script for applying changes and they only about their "namespace" :)

Hope I helped!

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: you can't

Longer answer:

Kafka is designed primarily for high performance and it does not have permission mechanisms e.g. you can't configure your brokers to allow producing but not consuming for certain clients. Any client that has access to brokers will be able to produce/consume data for all topics. The main idea is that the client itself is responsible for managing permissions.

Comment: Just a quick note for anyone that arrives to this old post. kafka now supports authentication and authrization. See:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html and
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_plain_clientconfig